# How to move Option from one Select Box to another, and vise versa

Tags: javascript

This is what I tried, but it doesn't move options at all I can't figure out why it doesn't work, I wrote down how I defined the right select box and button the other select box is empty

```
var ar = [];
var i = 0;

function move() { // moving from left select box to right
    var left = document.getElementById("left");
    var right = document.getElementById("right");

    var index = left.selectedIndex;

    var v = left.options[index].text; // takes value written in option
    if (index == -1) return;
    ar[i].push(parseInt(v));
    var new = document.createElement("option");
    new.text = v;
    right.add(new);
    left.remove(index);
    i++;
}


<html>
<body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><select id="left" class = "myform" size="10">
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>16</option>
                        <option>32</option>
                        <option>64</option>
                        <option>128</option>
                        <option>256</option>
                        <option>512</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <button onclick="move()">⇨</button>
                        </div>
                  <td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo: `selectedInex` should be `selectedIndex`

Comment: You don't need to create and remove elements, just move the element: `right.add(left.options[index])`

Comment: well it should move to another and delete form other one, that I didn't mentioned.

Comment: and I corrected typo and still it doesn't work

Comment: That's what my suggested code does. A DOM element can only be in one place at a time, so when you add it to `right` it's automatically removed from `left`.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? Add the HTML and show how you're calling the function.

Comment: Have you tried to open up the browser console and see what error(s) you get?

Comment: yes and it it shows ReferenceError: addElem is not defined

Comment: I added above how I defined the option box

Comment: thanks for the tips I managed to solve it :)